# Package that uses earphones as antenna to listen to fm radio?

Tags: linux, audio, application, streaming

I remember plugging in earphones in my 3G flipphone to listen to fm radio years ago. Are there any packages in Linux that have the same functionality? I mean local fm not internet radio.

Comment: software doesn't use antennas, just as software doesn't use e.g. internal combustion (but can be used to control an internal combustion engine, given *a lot* of hardware missing from a Linux computer usually, including the engine). Antennas are an analog hardware thing. There's a lot of things happening between an antenna and software, necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

um, that's a hardware capability that your Linux laptop or desktop PC simply doesn't have.

So, no, unless your Linux actually means "Linux in the shape of Android or another smartphone operating system running on a smartphone whose hardware actually contains an FM receiver".

What you **can** of course do is buy a device that can receive UHF signals (UHF is the frequency band that usually carries the FM broadcasts that you're referring to), and use software with that. An example of a software-defined radio receiver is the famous [RTL-SDR](https://osmocom.org/projects/rtl-sdr/wiki/Rtl-sdr) family of devices. Most modern Linux distros ship the [GQRX](https://gqrx.dk/) (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint…: `sudo apt install gqrx-sdr`; Fedora/RHEL+EPEL/…: `sudo dnf install gqrx`) software that you can use with that to receive FM broadcasts, AM broadcasts (if high enough in frequency), Aircraft voice comms…
But: again, this requires specific hardware, the cheap RTL-SDR dongles that you can buy cheap everywhere (if you're in Russia, that might be deservedly under embargoes due to waging war against a neighbor and having a hard time sourcing hardware).